# YAML Multiline String While Retaining Indentation and Newlines

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

**Background:**

This is an Ansible playbook using templates to CONSTRUCT a yaml file from a template. So basically I have a jinja2 template file with a line as such:

```
private_key: {{ myvar }}
```

Ansible uses yaml to define the variables. So I will fill in the `myvar` value something like this. Here I am using the `|` special character to define a multiline string:

```
myvar: |

        - "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----"
        - "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
        - "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
        - "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
        - "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
        - "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
        - "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
        - "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz="
        - "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

**However the output trims off the indentation:**

```
  private_key:
- "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----"
- "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
- "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
- "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
- "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
- "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
- "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
- "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz="
- "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

**Since the output file is a yaml itself, I need to retain the indentation. It seems no matter what I'll lose the indent.**

> I need the **end result** to look **EXACTLY** like this:

```
  private_key:
    - "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----"
    - "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
    - "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
    - "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
    - "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
    - "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
    - "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
    - "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz="
    - "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found the answer in a Google search right after posting the question.

Essentially the yaml string will strip indents, so in this case we have to use Jinja to insert spaces where they were stripped. Luckily this is super easy to do:

In the template file, I replaced this:

```
private_key: {{ myvar }}
```

With this:

```
private_key: {{ myvar | indent( width=4, indentfirst=True) }}
```

The `width` field can be adjusted for how many spaces of indentation are needed.

The actual variable declaration is done exactly like I posted in the question. However now with the indent added in the template, I now have the desired output with indentation:

```
  private_key:
    - "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----"
    - "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
    - "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
    - "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
    - "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
    - "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
    - "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfssadf"
    - "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz="
    - "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

Comment: Since Jinja 2.10, the parameter `indentfirst` has been renamed to just `first`: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.indent