# How to preserve leading whitespace in Jinja variable?

Tags: jinja2

I have a variable `source` containing multiple lines containing indentation (i.e. leading whitespaces):

```
.. admonition:: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

   Consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in dolor
   id massa convallis eleifend sed eu mauris.
```

However, when printed with `{{ source }}`, Jinja actually prints

```
.. admonition:: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in dolor
id massa convallis eleifend sed eu mauris.
```

i.e. it strips leading whitespaces! How to preserve them?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{{ source|indent }}
```

See jinja documentation [`indent`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#indent) (default indentation is four spaces, the first and blank lines are not indented - which is exactly what you need)

Comment: indent filter is not I'm looking for - it modifies a string on your request, but Jinja is stripping leading whitespaces without my request. In {{ interpolation }} it should print string as-is.

Comment: @Matt Unfortunately it appears that Jinja will automatically strip the indents in multiline strings, and `indent` should be the best possible solution. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55411080/13991219

Answer (score 0):

When reproducing your example this way:

```py
import jinja2

source = """
.. admonition:: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

   Consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in dolor
   id massa convallis eleifend sed eu mauris.
"""

template = jinja2.Template("""Content of 'source': {{ source }}
jinja2 version {{ version }} was used.""")

result = template.render(source=source, version=jinja2.__version__)
print(result)
```

the output was

```
Content of 'source':
.. admonition:: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

   Consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean in dolor
   id massa convallis eleifend sed eu mauris.

jinja2 version 2.11.3 was used.
```

(so the indentation of `source` was not modified by jinja2).